# Can anyone figure out how this guy does arbitrage?

Tags: nodejs, swaps, arbitrage, router, pairings

The owner of this tx record is constantly arbitraging for small amounts.

It does these directly via pair. So it's not using a router.

In my own testing I have always found that the amount of output is lower than the amount of input.

But how can this man achieve this?

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xedea66a8bf6d15e190cf1c90726a18636f454ed8882c795ff7e8c887b8097d56